# Copy the reference of an object or pass it in a method/constructor is thread safe?

Tags: java, multithreading, reference, synchronization, locking

I have an object that is shared in read/write between threads.

Assuming that the synchonization is correctely done, if A is the object previously initialized when no threads are running, when they start working is thread-safe do:

```
Object B = A;

DoSomething(A);
```

?

Comment: if synchronization is done correctly, then yes...it will inherently be thread-safe. I'm sorry, but this question makes little sense.

Comment: You'll need to post a little bit more of code to see the context and give proper answer.

Comment: There is always a thread running. The operations are thread safe, since the first line doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 1):

References can safely be shared; however, access to the actual object may require synchronization.